# MySQL installation woes

Tags: mysql

Trying to install MySQL on 20.04.4. After running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` it starts the server but there is a root password that is not known to me. I wanted to initialize it so I stopped the server and ran `mysqld --initialize-insecure --datadir=/tmp/mysql` - that generates no output at all, nothing written to the logs, and no files are created in /tmp/mysql. I stopped apparmor just to make sure that was not the culprit, but got the same results.  But one have any thoughts on what is going on here?

Comment: I would apply security fixes to your system asap; as your details (20.04.4) show you've not applied for *almost a year* if not longer; [this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 20.04.5 but installed systems upgraded to it before that date, and fully upgraded systems have reported themselves as 20.04.6 for some time now.

Comment: I tried to install it on another system and it worked perfectly. Looking for differences I see that the other system is running 20.04.5 and MySQL is 'Ver 8.0.34 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)' whereas on the one it doesn't work on is running 20.04.4 and MySQL is 'Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))'. Wonder why the difference.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo mysql`?

Comment: The OPs comment clearly shows the version where it works contains *more* security & other fixes applied; and the non-working version doesn't have those fixes applied; the difference is in details you provided yourself if you read your last comment OP.